# Is it possible to use jQuery selectors to access Struts2 elements without a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

I'm new to Struts2, but I'm consistently running into issues with jQuery selectors not being able to access any of the Struts2 tags we have defined in our jsps.

I'm assuming that they don't integrate without a lot of custom code or a plugin, but I haven't been able to find anything definitive in writing about it.  When I went to the [strut2-jQuery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) page they mention it's better to use a plugin in their faq, but not something that is required.

Am I missing something here?  If I have a struts2 tag for an element and try to select it using jQuery, it doesn't seeem to work.  I'm talking basic elements like

```
$('form').find(':input').change(function() { ...  //or

$('#testbutton').attr('disabled', true);  //or

 $('#formName').change(function() { 
          alert("Found form!"); 
     });
```

So when I look at view source, I see regular html code that gets generated from the tags, I just can't reach those specific elements using selectors if it was from a struts2 tag versus a regular html tag with the same jQuery selector code.

One other item, I'm using something like this to reference jQuery on the jsp page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: struts tags get converted into regular HTML code always so that's not the problem. Check the generated HTML code to see if the Ids you are using in your selectors are the same as in the generated html

Comment: Always look for the obvious.  I had a mix between the jsp's not recompiling and randomly missing the closing }); when I added a new function in.  When I did a clean build versus a rebuild the changes started working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the HTML is generated is not relevant to the client (the browser), and the client is ignorant of anything beyond the generated DOM.

If there's an ID, or it's an input, jQuery will find it--I've used plain jQuery (and Prototype) with S2 apps for years without issue.

Something else is wrong.

---

*Edited to show JSP, rendered HTML, and console output.*

JSP:

```
<s:form action="simpleForm">
  <s:textfield name="fname"/>
  <s:submit value="Go!"/>
</s:form>
```

Rendered HTML (assuming default `"xhtml"` theme):

```
<form id="simpleForm" name="simpleForm" action="/simpleForm.action" method="post">
  <table class="wwFormTable">
    <tr>
      <td class="tdLabel"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="" id="simpleForm_fname"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><div align="right"><input type="submit" id="simpleForm_0" value="Go!"/>
      </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table></form>
```

Some console output:

```
> $("form")
[<form id=​"simpleForm" name=​"simpleForm" action=​"/​simpleForm.action" method=​"post">​…​</form>​]
> $("form").find(":input")
[<input type=​"text" name=​"fname" value=​"d" id=​"simpleForm_fname">​, 
 <input type=​"submit" id=​"simpleForm_0" value=​"Go!">​]
> $("form").find("input") // Don't need the ":"
[<input type=​"text" name=​"fname" value=​"d" id=​"simpleForm_fname">​,
 <input type=​"submit" id=​"simpleForm_0" value=​"Go!">​]
```

Comment: Well, I'm not seeing what it is?  What about the last code example I posted, shouldn't that show up if I'm using the form id from the struts tag?

Comment: @JamesDrinkard Without knowing anything about the rendered HTML, seems like I'd just be guessing. I don't know what else to tell you--the client doesn't know *anything* about anything done on the server side, which is the only place tags matter. I'm editing to include JSP, rendered HTML, and the console output of jQuery commands. Check your JS console, try manual selectors, etc.--but again--the client doesn't care (or know) how HTML is generated, only the DOM it creates from the rendered HTML.

Comment: Dave, take a look at my latest update.  I think I'm referencing jQuery incorrectly to work with Struts2.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard Is it loading? Again, it has nothing to do with S2--that's a really old version, but you don't need to use the url tag to access absolute, non-app urls.

Comment: Yes, jQuery and Struts2 are both loading and working independently of each other.  I can run jQuery code on html elements and it works fine.  The Struts2 tags also work as expected.  I just can't reach the form or it's elements using the struts2 id's, or jQuery element selectors, or assigning a class, save for textfields.  Those are the only inputs that jQuery can communicate with on the form.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard Then something else is wrong--what you're saying makes no sense, and there's nothing more I can do with the info you've provided. JQ knows nothing about S2, and doesn't care how the HTML is generated. Try a more modern version of JQ, or put a minimally-failing app on github and if I have time I'll take a look.

Comment: Okay. Many thanks for your time.  I think it's solved now and your original answer was the correct one, I had a problem with the way I was setting up my main function call.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard *whew* Although `$(function() {...})` should work too; it's the form I use all the time.

Comment: It may just have been not doing a final closing brace with all the functions instead of trying to run them each independently.  I'm past it now though, thankfully!